# Dynamic population of Bootstrap 4 carousel via Angular 4 not displaying images

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-4

I am trying to dynamically populate a Bootstrap 4 carousel via an ngFor iterating over an array of strings that contain the image urls.  The carousel is not displaying the images, though looking at the markup generated everything looks fine.  I'm guessing that the component is rendering before Angular is adding in the divs for each slide, as the "carousel slide" div has a height of 0px, which I think is what is hiding the slides themselves.

Behind-the-scenes I have an exposed property named "primarySlideshowImages" containing an array of urls:

```
    ngOnInit() {
        this.primarySlideshowImages = this.photoService.getImageLists(ImageListKeys.BrochureProductsPrimary);
    }
```

The HTML markup looks like this:

```
<div id="carousel1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div *ngFor="let image of primarySlideshowImages; let i = index" class="carousel-item {{ (i == 0) ? 'active' : ''}}">
        <img class="d-block img-fluid w-100" [src]="image" >
    </div>
</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel1" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Previous</span> </a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel1" role="button" data-slide="next"> <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="sr-only">Next</span> </a>
```

FYI, I have tested this by hardcoding rather than dynamically adding the images, and everything renders just fine.  I think it's a timing thing, but given my relative unfamiliarity with this technology I just don't know how to even search for a solution at this point.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.  I do recognize that there are other components and approaches I could use - the ng-bootstrap components, open-source components, purchasable ones, etc.  I'd like to try to figure this out using the bootstrap components because I'm pretty new at this technology and hate to jump to an easy solution if there is something I just don't understand that I should be doing.  Thanks again for any help you may offer.

Comment: if we want to display more than 1 image .i.e..may be 3 or 4 in one slide...then how it will work...plz help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be that the div containing the image has a width and/or height of the div containing the image is/are 0.

Try setting a style on them. e.g .carousel-item {width:200px; height:200px;}

Also, try checking if the images are being retrieved by the browser using the Network tab on the dev tools.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughts on this.  In between the time I posted the question and now I changed out the photos with ones I had been meaning to put in place.  A rebuild and refresh and everything is rendering.  I have no idea what I was doing wrong, but it was likely something really stupid.  I had tried to explicitly set the height, but it seemed that the carousel was overriding that.  I hadn't checked the network tab to see if the images were being retrieved, though I do know the urls were right.  Anyway, thank you very much!